# How to use OAuth security for RESTful backend

Tags: java, rest, oauth

I have a REST backend that is accessed using REST request calls. This backend has a thin client front end and a plugin that consumes the REST api.

Currently the security is implemented using HTTP basic authentication.

Now I want to implement oauth as security mechanism. I have read all about oauth but could not find a working example of securing RESTful backend using oauth.

Please could any one guide me on how can i implement oauth security in my app?

Comment: is the client expected to be a web browser or some other program?

Comment: This is a non-trivial task. I would recommend looking at how [RESTEasy does it](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.2.GA/userguide/html/Authentication.html), as a start.

Comment: OAuth is a delegation protocol. Implementing it for authentication is pretty challenging and requires another protocol like OpenID Connect on top of it. Or the clients need to be connected thru an OAuth provider like Google or Twitter and the tokens would need to be authorized.

Comment: @jtahlborn :client is web browser and a plugin for some other program

Comment: @DmitryStarosta some examples using oauth with openID or when the client is connected thru an oauth provided would really be appreciated. Looking forward to some links.

Comment: i asked what the client is because oauth is a _very_ painful protocol to use with a non-web-brwoser client (since the flow is _built_ around a browser).  i would advise against it in this scenario.

Comment: @jtahlborn actually we use HTTP calls to post and get data from our services.

Comment: DotNetOpenAuth is a very popular .NET OAuth library that is officially supported by the MVC 4.0. It has the necessary documentation as well as sample projects that implement the protocol. http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/documentation/

Comment: And I second jtahlborn comments.

Comment: note, i wasn't commenting on the protocol you use (http), just the client type (non-web-browser).

Comment: @DmitryStarosta sorry for not mentioning but i am using java and spring not .NET, so any library for spring?